# Access Syntax Issues: multiple inner joins cause record number reduction

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, inner-join

My problem is that I would like to make a query of multiple tables, but as well as I increase the number of inner joins, the number of the resulted record numbers decrease.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No], atabla.[Outgoing date]        
AS [ext(1)time], btabla.[Outgoing date] 

FROM ((((((Daily_Output20151013 

INNER JOIN (SELECT [Lot no], [Outgoing date] FROM Daily_Output20151013 
WHERE ((mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],4,1) = 'S')) 
    and (mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],5,1)='T') 
    and (mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],6,1)='R') 
    and (mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],8,1)='1'))  AS atabla ON Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = atabla.[Lot No]) 

INNER JOIN (SELECT [Lot no], [Outgoing date] FROM Daily_Output20151013 
WHERE ((mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],4,1) = 'P')) 
    and (mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],5,1)='L') 
    and (mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],6,1)='G') 
    and (mid(Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern],8,1)='1'))  AS btabla ON Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = btabla.[Lot No])
```

This is a little extract from the code. The reduction problem appears, because sometimes these fields contain no data, and I think, Access does not show any record that misses at least one data.

My question is how to solve that problem and show all data

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, this will return all records of the left table (Daily_Output20151013) together with the matching records of your joined subqueries.

Note: if you have many LEFT JOINs like that in the query, performance may suffer. It may be necessary to save the subqueries (atabla, btabla) as named queries and use them instead.